# How to import Windows API functions manually?

Tags: winapi

For the fun, I want to create a (*working*) executable that doesn't depend on the CRT. It wasn't that hard after reading some articles, so I settled on:

```
/* test.c */
int main(){
    return 0;
}
...
/* Compiling & Linking: */
cl /c /O2 /Ox /Os test.c
link /ENTRY:main /NODEFAULTLIB /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS /ALIGN:16 /ignore:4108 test.obj
```

So far so good, but I would like to be able to call the functions of Windows API. For example, how should I link the following piece of code?:

```
#define UNICODE
#include <windows.h>

int main(){
    MessageBox
        (NULL, TEXT("Hello Stackoverflow!"), TEXT("Hello Stackoverflow"), MB_OK);
    return 0;
}
```

I read the following articles but couldn't come up with a solution:
[Minicrt](http://www.benshoof.org/blog/minicrt/), [Small Programs](http://www.benshoof.org/blog/small-programs/), [Tiny PE](http://www.phreedom.org/solar/code/tinype/), [Techniques for reducing Executable size](http://www.catch22.net/tuts/minexe).

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with dropping CRT, you would still have it without that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Link against `user32.lib`

```
link /ENTRY:main /NODEFAULTLIB /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS /ALIGN:16 /ignore:4108 test.obj user32.lib
```

Look up in MSDN which library the function belongs to, and link against it.

Comment: Lool I can't believe it is that simple :), all that time I was doing: `#pragma comment(lib, "user32.lib")`. Could you please explain what is the difference between supplying the name of the library to the linker, and going the `#pragma` way?

Comment: @AraK There should be none. I see no `#pragma` in the source, are you saying it didn't work?

Comment: I tried it, but it didn't work. That is why I didn't include it in the question.

Comment: @AraK I think there is no difference but you should use `#pragma comment(lib,"user32")` NOT `#pragma comment(lib,"user32.lib")`.

Comment: @Adban: No, it doesn't matter whether you include the extension.

Comment: @CodyGray: I tried it with extension, doen't work! (Be sure that it is not be included in your compiler options).